What is this coin shaped object?

Question:
I found this coin-like thing in my grandfather's closet. To provide some context, we live in Assam (state in India), specifically in Dibrugarh. My grandfather's family has been here since before independence(1947). When I asked my grandfather he said he did not know what this was.
I am pretty sure it is not an authentic relic, probably a replica of some kind, but I'm still curious to know what exactly this is. So far, I've come to the conclusion that the script is similar to Arabic. The coin is as heavy as 2 ₹10 coins and the diameter is roughly 3.5cm.
Please, help me find out what this could be.

Are the markings on one side only?

You should look for a forum about ancient coins (like r/ancientcoins) because this looks like the reproduction of a 13th century Seljuk dirham, but you need people who can read the text.

@SteveBird yes, the markings are on both sides

Please provide an image of the markings on the other side.

@justCal it's the same on both sides

Two possible lines of inquiry: (1) token money, as used by certain businesses or (2) an Islamic prayer medallion. Also, the language for the script could be Persian.
